# For loop after for loop produces wrong output Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to use for loops to iterate through some Yahoo Finance data and calculate the return the papers. The problem is that I want to do this for different times, and that I have a document containing the different start and end dates. This is the code I have been using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime

# This function is just used to download the data I want and saveing 
#it  to a csv file.

def downloader():

    start = datetime(2005,1,1)
    end = datetime(2010,1,1)
    tickers = ['VIS', 'VFH', 'VPU']
    stock_data = DataReader(tickers, "yahoo", start, end)
    price = stock_data['Adj Close']
    price.to_csv('data.csv')

downloader()

#reads the data into a Pandas DataFrame.
price = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col = 'Date', parse_dates = True)

#Creates a Pandas DataFrame that holdt multiple dates. The formate on this is the same as the format I have on the dates when I load the full csv file of dates.
inp = [{'start' : datetime(2005,1,3), 'end' : datetime(2005,12,30)},
       {'start' : datetime(2005,2,1), 'end' : datetime(2006,1,31)},
       {'start' : datetime(2005,3,1), 'end' : datetime(2006,2,28)}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

#Everything above this is not part of the original script, but this 
#is  just used to replicate the problem I am having.


results = pd.DataFrame()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    start = row['start']
    end = row['end']

price_initial = price.ix[start:end]

    for column1 in price_initial:

        price1 = price_initial[column1]
        startprice = price1.ix[end]
        endprice = price1.ix[start]
        momentum_value = (startprice / endprice)-1

        results = results.append({'Ticker' : column1, 'Momentum' :  momentum_value}, ignore_index=True)
        results = results.sort(columns = "Momentum", ascending = False).head(1)

    print(results.to_csv(sep= '\t', index=False))
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. But I suspect there is something about the way I iterate over or the way I save the output from the script.

The output I get is this:

```
Momentum    Ticker
0.16022263953253435 VPU

Momentum    Ticker
0.16022263953253435 VPU

Momentum    Ticker
0.16022263953253435 VPU
```

That is clearly not correct. Hope someone can help me get this right.

Comment: My output is **Momentum Ticker
0.143801422643 VPU** what wrong ?

Comment: Why do you call `.head(1)`?

Comment: yes, same code..**VFH 0.123849217399
VIS 0.119842689809
VPU 0.143801422643
Momentum Ticker
0.143801422643 VPU**

Comment: I forgot to add that I just wanted the one with the highest return over the period, thats why I call .head(1). The problem is that the code should produce three outputs, one for each of the start to end dates, and they should ofcourse not be the same ones. SDilmac are you getting those results running the code? I just tried to rerun it, and I still get the same as before

Comment: **print always save time**

Comment: I just noticed that the code was pasted inn the wrong way, and that it was missing some indentations after the first for loop.